# Where do I now place "//= require thredded" with rails 6 and webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I really cannot get my head around this js and webpack stuff.

I am trying to use Thredded in a new Rails 6 app. I've done everything except being able to deal with the `//= require thredded` requirement.

There is no application.js in the assets directory any more and I have no idea what to do to have the javascript included in my app.

I've tried adding import "thredded" into my application.js file in the webpack directory. It doesn't work.

How would I go about including the js from the gem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you had ```<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>``` in your layout 'application.html.erb'

Comment: Hi @RonanLouarn. I have added the tags which are expected in Rails 6 (I think), namely: `    <%# All assets are defined in Webpacker app/javascripts now %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>

Comment: There's some info in the Thredded README about Webpack, have you followed these steps? https://github.com/thredded/thredded#add-thredded-javascripts-webpack

Comment: @rossta I did follow the instructions and things were better, but there was then another problem which I reported as a bug but I don't think anything has been done. It wasn't rendering the text properly when I was typing in the text_area.